# Swift - causing an infinite loop while declaring a variable outside the function

Tags: ios, swift, function, infinite-loop, variable-declaration

I have started learning Swift recently and it was my first coding language. I encountered a difficulty while declaring a variable outside the function and still couldn't figure out why it caused an infinite loop.

```
func addItem(item: Int) {
        box.append(item)
    }
var topItem: Int?
func pickUpItem() -> Int? {
//    var topItem: Int?
    guard box.count > 0 else {
        return topItem
    }
    topItem = box[box.count - 1]
    box.remove(at: box.count - 1)
    return topItem
}
var box: [Int] = []
addItem(item: 667)
addItem(item: 651)
addItem(item: 604)
while let num = pickUpItem() {
    print(num)
}
```

However, if I declared the variable inside the function, everything went fine. Why was that?

```
func addItem(item: Int) {
        box.append(item)
    }
//var topItem: Int?
func pickUpItem() -> Int? {
    var topItem: Int?
    guard box.count > 0 else {
        return topItem
    }
    topItem = box[box.count - 1]
    box.remove(at: box.count - 1)
    return topItem
}
var box: [Int] = []
addItem(item: 667)
addItem(item: 651)
addItem(item: 604)
while let num = pickUpItem() {
    print(num)
}
```

Comment: In the first case, you never go back to the case were `topItem` is `nil`. When you declare it inside the method and you get box.count > 0, you return nil. But when declared externally, it has the previous value. So when you do `return topItem` in the `guard`, it's not nil, so `while let` is valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's outside the function it gets a value from the first group of  elements so it will never be nil when the array is empty hence infinite loop , while inside the function it's value is decided according to current array elements

It could work properly outside if you reset it like this at the beginning of the function

```
var topItem: Int?
func pickUpItem() -> Int? {
  topItem = nil
  ....
}
```

**OR**

```
guard box.count > 0 else {
    return nil
}
```